# MYSQL trigger see if record exists first?

Tags: mysql

So I have a trigger that works on update. Totally works fine.

Insert in cars(date, id, parent_id) values (date, ford, 2)

What I need to do is to actually check to see if the parent_id already exists. If it does do nothing but if it does not exist then do the insert statement.

right now i have

```
SET @myVar1 = (SELECT parent_id from cars where parent_id = NEW.id);
IF @myVar1 = NULL;
Insert in cars(date, id, parent_id) values (date, ford, 2);
ENDIF;
```

I keep getting sysntax error. How am I writing this worng?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is on this line:

```
Insert in cars(date, id, parent_id) values (date, ford, 2);
```

The `in` should be `INTO`. That's the syntax error.

That said, you might be better served with an [`INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) or [`REPLACE INTO`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html) statement rather than an on-update trigger. Be careful with `REPLACE INTO` though, as it can be dangerous (but the danger can be somewhat mitigated by using transactions).

Comment: also INSERT on duplicate key wont work because parent_id is not a key and i dobnt want to insert when there is a existing parent_id.

Comment: The query you posted does, effectively, the same thing as setting parent_id as a `UNIQUE KEY` and using `INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY`.

Answer (score 1):

dunno if this what you really need. but you can try this one

```
SET @myVar1 = (SELECT parent_id from cars where parent_id = NEW.id);
IF (@myVar1 is NULL) then
Insert into cars(`date`, id, parent_id) values (date(), new.`name`, new.id);
END IF;
```

or

```
Insert into cars(`date`, id, parent_id) values (date(), new.`name`, new.id) on duplicate key update `date`=date();
```

on mysql must be "end if" not "endif".

new.`name` is assumes that id field on car from trigger table

you can use on duplicate key update if cars table use primary key or unique key like mention above

and if you doesn't want to change any record if exists then after key update change to id=id or you can use any field.